# Can neural networks have multi-dimensional output nodes?

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow

I'm trying to understand what's possible with TensorFlow's output layer. Specifically, are outputs always a flat array?

Since a neuron (or 'unit', in TF) has just one number, and there is only one set of outputs, it seems that output must have a single dimension. With one-hot probabilities, this is easy to understand. But what about an image?

If my output is going to be a picture, can I have TF output a multi-dimensional array of pixels, e.g. [[r0, g0, b0], [r1, g1, b1], ...]? If so, how would that network be constructed? How would I define the output layer's dimensionality/shape?

The only param I know of that defines output shape is this, from tf.layers.dense, which seems inherently one-dimensional:

- **units** *(number) Positive integer, dimensionality of the output space.*

Any help you can provide is greatly appreciated!

Reference: https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#layers.dense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output layer does not have to be 1D (excl. batch size) but even if it is, it does not necessary mean you cannot transform it to a n dimensional space. Consider an autoencoder used to reconstruct an image:

1. In the simplest case we could flatten a image (e.g. 24 x 24 pixels) and learn a network to predict the 24 x 24 pixels (output a 1D image). These pixels can then be transformed back to an 2D image (https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/autoencoder). So in other words, even if your network outputs a 1D shape, nothing prevent you from reconstructing it to a higher space.
2. We can achieve similar results as stated in the point above, by using an encoding network (convolutional + pooling layers) followed by a decoding layer (transposed convolutional + up sampling layers). In this case you can effectively generate a 2D image directly (https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/cvae).

You can also look at image segmentation networks for inspiration of how higher dimensions outputs can be generated.

Comment: Thanks very much for the info!

Comment: Just to clarify - is the output made up of multiple layers with hierarchical structure? Or is the output flat, but TensorFlow is 'packaging' that flat array into nested arrays (or a tensor)? I'm confused in trying to visualize this setup, mainly because every graph I've ever seen has just one output layer. I suppose it could be arbitrarily broken up, e.g. 10 nodes that are _treated as_ 2 sets of 5, by the predict() call, for example. - thanks again! I will research the material you suggest.